# Define a GLib.Variant in Python

Tags: python, glib, dbus, gvariant

I am trying to define a `GLib.Variant` data type in Python to use it with the `pydbus` library. This is my attempt to do so:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

from gi.repository import GLib
from pydbus import SessionBus

var1 = GLib.Variant.new_variant('draw-cursor', False)
var2 = GLib.Variant.new_variant('framerate', 30)

bus = SessionBus()
calling = bus.get('org.gnome.Shell.Screencast', '/org/gnome/Shell/Screencast')

calling.Screencast('out.webm', {var1, var2})
```

However it says `TypeError: GLib.Variant.new_variant() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)`. And I can see that clear. But then how can I assign the values for what I will define? Shouldn't it be a dictionary like `{'framerate': 30}`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second failure (`AttributeError: 'Variant' object has no attribute 'items'`) seems to be because `pydbus` expects you to pass in a `dict`, rather than a `GLib.Variant`, and it unconditionally wraps whatever you pass it in a `GLib.Variant`. This means it tries to get the `items` from the `options` variant, which fails because `GLib.Variant` doesn’t support that.

This code works with `pydbus`:

```
calling.Screencast('out.webm', {
    'draw-cursor': GLib.Variant('b', False),
    'framerate': GLib.Variant('i', 30)
})
```

Answer (score 2):

The options argument has type `a{sv}`, so you probably need to provide the types explicitly:

```
options = GLib.Variant('a{sv}', {
    'draw-cursor': GLib.Variant('b', False),
    'framerate': GLib.Variant('i', 30),
})
```

Comment: Now it says: `AttributeError: 'Variant' object has no attribute 'items'`. I don't know if this was a bug in GLib itself.

Comment: It works for me; this is the latest GLib and Python 3 by the way.

Comment: Well I have the same too. Yet it yields the error. The complete code is: https://pastebin.mozilla.org/8976332 Right?

Comment: You didn't say the error was from the `Screencast` call now. Are you sure you need to pass a variant there in the first place?

Comment: Yes definitely. It was mentioned in some documentation beside a lot of other places. Also this is an example: http://askubuntu.com/questions/359587/how-to-pass-asv-arguments-to-gdbus

Comment: That example is for gdbus command line, not Python. Are you really sure you need to pass a variant object to that method *in Python*? The error you quoted seems to indicate it's looking for a dictionary.

Comment: Actually you seem to be right. I check the gobject properties and found this: http://i.imgur.com/9Dk6qyJ.png But if it was a dictionary. How can I pass it like this type then?